# Display image in asp div

Tags: html, css

My problem is that, after i was able to display my medium blob in mysql database in my jsp, i  cannot position the image with my css.

What i want is to position it inside a div that has a fixed width and height.

```
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

            Statement stmnt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            OutputStream o = null;
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/uShare";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";
            PreparedStatement ps;
            Blob image = null;
            byte[] imgData = null;
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                stmnt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select foto from utilizadores where idUtilizador = 13");
                if (rs.next()) {
                    image = rs.getBlob("foto");
                    imgData = image.getBytes(1, (int) image.length());
                    out.println("encontrou imagem");
                }
                //mostra
                response.setContentType("image/gif");
                o = response.getOutputStream();
                o.write(imgData);

        %>
        <div style="float: right; width: 20%; height: 20%;">
            <%   
                o.flush();


            %>

        </div>

        <%
                o.close();
                stmnt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you to all.

Comment: What does this have to do with java/jsp/mysql at all? Those are purely server-side technologies. You're needing help with html and css - **CLIENT** technologies.

Comment: You are right, but i am thinking that might be there other way to upload the image into the asp page. I will remove mySql tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer but the site doesn't let me reply within 8 hours.T hanks to everyone. I found a temporary solution, and because this is for academic purposes only it´s ok.

The solution is. When i want to display a image in a ing tag, i always have to give the tag the url.
There are two possibilities:

- you cam pass the image through servlet;
- Or like the one i did, i displayed the image in a Jsp page then i grab it on the other jsp with the first jsp url.

Jsp for display the image:

```
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <link href="css/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <%

            Statement stmnt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            OutputStream o = null;
            String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/uShare";
            String username = "root";
            String password = "";
            PreparedStatement ps;
            Blob image = null;
            byte[] imgData = null;
            try {
                Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                stmnt = con.createStatement();
                rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select foto from utilizadores where idUtilizador = 13");
                if (rs.next()) {
                    image = rs.getBlob("foto");
                    imgData = image.getBytes(1, (int) image.length());
                    out.println("encontrou imagem");
                }
                //mostra

                response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
                o = response.getOutputStream();
                o.write(imgData);
                o.flush();

                response.flushBuffer();


                stmnt.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then the end user jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="testeImagem.jsp" alt="foto" style="width: 200px; height: 200px">

    </body>
</html>
```

Of course this is just an example.
Thanks to all, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score -1):

set image width as 100% so that it will get fit inside a fixed length of div

Comment: And how do i do that? I flushed the output stream into the div, and the div has fixed width and height. Doesn´t that means that the flushed output has to fit the div?

Comment: dear Xaver are you facing the same problem like the question asked by the user?